Почему объект с Network Identity выключается при загрузке сцены
У меня на сцене есть объект GameController В котором находятся скрипты GameManager и Network Identity. Когда я подключаюсь как хост, то всё в порядке, но когда я подключаюсь как клиент, GameController отключается.

using Mirror;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

public class GameManager : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SyncVar(hook = nameof(CreateStackOfCards))]
    [SerializeField] private string Cards_text_mass;
    public float cardBias = .25f;
    public GameObject cardsGO;
    public GameObject cardPrefab;
    public List<GameObject> cards = new List<GameObject>(); 
    private void Awake()
    {
       // DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (isServer)
        {
            CreateMassOfCards();
        }
    }

    public void StopGame()
    {
        if (NetworkServer.active && NetworkClient.active)
        {
            NetworkManager.singleton.StopHost();
        }
        else if (NetworkClient.isConnected) 
        {
            NetworkManager.singleton.StopClient();
        }
        else if (NetworkServer.active)
        {
            NetworkManager.singleton.StopServer();
        }
    }

    [Server]
    public void CreateMassOfCards()
    {
        print("Create Cards Mass");
        char[,] grid = new char[10, 10];
        char letter = 'A';
        List<string> cards_text = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            char digit = '1';

            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            {
                grid[i, j] = letter;
                int f = j + 1;
                string t = grid[i, j].ToString() + f.ToString();
                cards_text.Add(t);
                digit++;
            }

            letter++;
        }
        for (int i = cards_text.Count - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            int j = Random.Range(0, i + 1);
            // обменять значения data[j] и data[i]
            var temp = cards_text[j];
            cards_text[j] = cards_text[i];
            cards_text[i] = temp;
        }
        string texts = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cards_text.Count; i++)
        {
            texts += cards_text[i] + ";";
        }
        Cards_text_mass = texts.ToString();
    }


    private void CreateStackOfCards(string old_value, string new_value)
    {
        string cards_texts = new_value;
        print("Create Cards");
        print(cards_texts);
        float c = 0;
        string[] texts = cards_texts.Split(';');
        if (cards != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.Count; i++)
            {
                Destroy(cards[i]);
            }
            cards.Clear();
        }
        for (int f = 0; f < texts.Length - 1; f++)
        {
            print(texts[f]);
            GameObject card = Instantiate(cardPrefab, cardsGO.transform);
            card.name = texts[f];
            card.GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = texts[f];
            card.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector2(c, -60);
            c -= cardBias;
            cards.Add(card);
            print(card);
        }
    }
}

Я пробовал ставить Force Shown на Network Identity, пробовал прописывать DontDestroyOnLoad в GameManager, но GameController всё равно отключается

в консоль предупреждения не пишет?
